# Proof that if $f$ is continuous and of bounded variation then $h(t) =x + \int_{[0,t]}h(s) df(s)$ iff $ h(t) = xe^{f(t)} $

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

My attempt:

I tried to use the chain rule to prove that $ h(t) = xe^{f(t)} $ implies that $h(t) =x +  \int_{[0,t]}h(s) df(s)$ but it was fruitless. To prove the other way I tried to prove that $h(t)exp\{-f(t)\} $ is constant w.r.t $t$, for that purpose I tried to derive $h(t)exp\{-f(t)\} $ w.r.t. f (in the radon nikodyn sense). But I can't formalize that
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{df}h(t)exp\{-f(t)\} & = h(t)*\frac{d}{df} exp\{-f(t)\} + exp\{-f(t)\}*\frac{dh(t)}{df }\\
&= -h(t) exp\{-f(t)\} + exp\{-f(t)\}h(t)\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been edited after I posted this.

If $f$ is continuously differentiable then $h(t)=x+\int_0^{t} h(s)f'(s)ds$ and so $h'(t)=h(t)f(t)$. This gives $h(t)=c e^{f(t)}$. But $h(0)=x$ so we get $h(t)=xe^{f(t)}$.

Comment: Thanks, but the only thing that I know about f is that it is continuous.

Comment: @Marcela $\int h(s)df(s)$ cannot be defined for an arbitrary  continuous function $f$.

Comment: That's true, I just edit my question.f needs to be of bounded variation